# How can a Discord bot reply to only certain users?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am looking for a way to make a Discord bot which either reacts or replies to only certain users. It can choose the user by either role or ID, but I can not seem to get it working. This is what I have tried:

```
if (message.author.id === 'myDiscordID') {
        message.reply('hello!').then(r => {
        });
    }
```

I am coding in Discord JS, if that helps. This is the entire index.js file:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {

    if (message.author.id === 'myDiscordID') {
        message.reply('hello!').then(r => {
        });
    }

});
client.login(token);
```

The file runs fine, the bot comes online, and then it prints 'Ready!' to the console, however, the rest of the code doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I`ts look like this must work.

Are you sure bot in your server and have permissions to read message ?
Try this ready block

```js
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
    const guildList = client.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.name)
    console.join(`Bot go online in ${guildList.length}`)
    console.log(guildList.join('\n'))
});
```

And some solutin to check user.id or roles includes:

`console.log(message.content)` for check is this event triggeret.

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    console.log(message.content)
    if (message.author.id === '') {
        message.reply('author contain')
    }

    if (message.member.roles.cache.has('ROLE ID')) {
        message.reply('role contain')
    }

    if(message.member.roles.cache.some(role => ['ID1', 'ID2'].includes(role.id)) {
        message.reply('some role contain')
    }   

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also having a problem with that. Here is the solution that worked for me.

```
const userID = "The_user's_id";

bot.on("message", function(message) {
    if(message.author.id === userID) {
        message.react('emoji name or id');
    }
});
```

Note: to find the id of a user, just right click him and press "copy ID".